increase integer and use it as array key with some prefix : Unsupported operand types: string + int
This is my code:
$dns = ['host'=>['mynewcomp2','www']];

foreach($dns as $i=>$dn){
        $j=$i+1;
        $args['HostName'.$j] = $dns['host'][$i];
}

I get error when I want to increase $i and use it as array key with some prefix

Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int

The error is in this line: $j=$i+1;
I need the result like this:
$args['HostName1'] = $dns['host'][0];
$args['HostName2'] = $dns['host'][1];


What is the runtime value of $i when the error occurs?  Can you update this to a [mcve] which can be independently executed to observe the problem?

$i is index counter start from 0 to count array $dns

print_r($dns) and see the real keys. I also see $dns['host'] that means that $i is host. And you probably need foreach($dns['host']....

@ZiadNassar: Don't just describe what you assume the value should be, debug and observe the actual exact value.  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

$i is index counter start from 0 to count array $dns...it can't be - if it was, you wouldn't have this error. As per the comments above, debug and test your code properly so you can see what value it really has.

Thanks for the update. You need to loop through $dns['host'], not just $dns. If you loop through $dns the only index in there is "host", which clearly isn't an integer - hence the error! Your numeric array is inside the "host" property. See Juan's answer below.

If you want to get the list of HOSTS then you have to extract this list and then browse it. In your example you browse a list of DNS and not the list of HOSTS.
// Initialization
$dns    = ['host'=>['mynewcomp2','www']];
$args   = array();

// Extraction
$hosts  = $dns['host'];

// Construction Array
foreach($hosts as $key => $value)   $args["HostName".($key+1).""] = $value;

// Display
echo "<pre>".print_r($args,true)."</pre>"; 


Just to note, the "Extraction" step isn't really necessary. Looping directly (i.e. foreach($dns["host"] as $key => $value)) will work just fine, which saves line of code and another copy of the array using up the server's memory - demo: https://3v4l.org/VU9H7

@ADyson Yes I know and I completely agree with you but I preferred to “show the steps” rather than putting a single line.

@Juan, Adding the extraction does nothing to "show the steps" - it just adds bloat and obscures any actual changes you made.

@LukeStevenson Giving names to things can aid in understanding. I wouldn't feel this necessary in code I'm writing for myself, but I like to do this in answers for educational purpose.

Note that print_r has a second parameter to make it a function. With it, you can write: echo '<pre>', print_r($args, true), '</pre>';
